# How to hide gretel breadcrumb in some views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, breadcrumbs

I am using Gretel Breadcrumb gem https://github.com/lassebunk/gretel for adding breadcrumbs in my rails application.I am able to generate all breadcrumbs but i want that the breadcrumbs should not be displayed on some particular views e.g. user show page.How can i do that ??

Comment: You can add condition to check controller and action, something like
`<%= breadcrumbs(pretext: "You are here: ",
                separator: " &rsaquo; ") if params[:controller]!="users" && params[:action]!="show"%>`

Comment: i want breadcrumbs to be created but not to be displayed and i think if i use the above code,breadcrumb will not be created at all.Please correct me if i m wrong

Comment: Yes, It wont create for users show page. If u want to hide it then do it with css, wrap the breadcrumb in a div container and give it specific class for that page only so then u can hide entire container for that page only.